# display taxonomy slug from term ID

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms, categories

I'm trying to display the taxonomy slug from the term ID, thus my current code is like so:

```
<?php $catinfo = get_category(array_pop(get_sub_field('sector_selector'))); ?>
<?php print $catinfo->slug; ?>
```

which isn't printing anything, a `var_dump($catinfo);` produces the following:

```
array(1) { [0]=> int(59) }
```

In theory `<?php print $catinfo->slug; ?>` should print the taxonomy slug, but it isn't? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [get_term_by()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) for this

```
<?php
$term_id = array_pop(get_sub_field('sector_selector'));
$catinfo = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, 'name_of_the_taxonomy' );
print $catinfo->slug;
```

Comment: and how would this be implemented in the example above? As I can't seem to get it to work?

Comment: @user1374796 I have edited my answer, I am assuming that `array_pop(get_sub_field('selector_selector'))` returns term id as per your question.

Comment: yes this is what I did, but I keep getting `Missing argument 3 for get_term_by()` etc etc, error message. I'm not sure why?

Comment: @user1374796 You have to give the name of the taxonomy as the third argument.